# JSF Temporary variable outside Bean

Tags: jsf

Is there any way to store temporary data without using Bean?

It's like I have tab-like stored information and I want to allow user to click on tab and switch displayed data and mark active tab and stuff. I think this data shouldn't be stored in Back-Bean so I'm looking for other way to do this. Something like:

```
<f:commandLink>
    <ui:param name="param" value="1" />
<f:commandLink>
```

This could be great if ui:param wasn't parsed once on page initialization. Any ideas?

Comment: Is there any reason not to have it stored at managed bean? JSF is a stateful framework, so it keeps a model of what you're viewing at the server. You could make the bean request scoped to be recreated for each request, but does it makes any sense in your case?

Comment: @XtremeBiker depending on requirement, the bean to hold the data may be `@ViewScoped` or `@SessionScoped`.

Comment: `<c:set>`? `<f:setPropertyActionListener>`? Such a general question is hard to answer without a specific concrete functional requirement.